# Why does the force in a motor move perpendicularly instead of towards each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

This may be a peculiar way of asking but given the image below:
[image]
Flemings left-hand rule

How does the wire experience a force upwards rather than being attracted directly to the magnet? If a current in a wire creates a magnetic effect, what makes the wire jump upwards rather than towards the magnet? I understand Flemings's left-hand rule says that’s true, but why is it true if the wire and the magnet are attracted due to a current? I know nothing about this matter other than the fact that magnets attract or repel and that currents create magnetic fields.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

"... if the wire and the magnet are attracted due to a current ..." They aren't! The wire, as you know, experiences a 'sideways' force. This can be traced to the *magnetic Lorentz* forces ($\vec F=q\ \vec v \times \vec B$) experienced by the free electrons moving through the wire.

But a piece of wire carrying a current *can* behave like a magnet, both in the field it produces and the forces it experiences, if it is wound into a *coil*. It experiences a couple when placed in an external magnetic field, 'broadside on' to that field. If the coil is placed in a non-uniform external magnetic field, it will experience a net force. For example if one of its ends is placed near the North or South pole of a magnet it will be attracted or repelled, just as if it were another magnet.

In your diagram we have a 'coil' of a single turn, more or less in a single plane. The normal to the coil's plane is at right angles to the external field, so we have the broadside-on configuration. And the coil does indeed turn.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field lines between the magnet are changed being the combination of the magnetic field due to coil and the magnetic field due to the magnets.

This is "illustrated" below.

[image]

What is set up is a pair of "catapult" fields.
One way of explaining the origin of the forces on the coil is to use the idea that magnetic field lines are in a state of tension and so are like stretched elastic bands trying to straighten out.